# Can't link to CSS file in HTML

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

I can't seem to link to my CSS file in my HTML. Below is my HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Welcome.</title>

    <style>
        <link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <p> This paragraph has no ID</p>
    <div id="block">
        <h2>Hello this is h2 text.</h2>
    </div>

    <h3> This is a h3 tag with an id that should give it some styling</h3>
    <p id="examplep"> This is an example paragraph has an ID that should give it large font.</p>

</body>

</html>
```

Here is main.css, which is located in the same folder as my HTML file:

```
body{
background-color: blue;
}
p{
font-size: 50;
}

#block{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: -150px;
    margin-left: -150px;

    color: black;
    background-color: white;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
#examplep{
font-size: 50px;
}
```

Sorry about the crappy formatting. Anyway, I believe it is a problem linking. Shouldn't the background be blue, The paragraph without ID be size 50, the div be a white box in the middle of the page with white text, and the examplep paragraph be size 50 also? I have tried everything within my knowledge to fix it but I can't seem to do it. Any help?

Comment: You can link by entering full path of that css if not working like above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't enclose it in **style tag**. Simply write

```
  <link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: yeah just realized this as you posted it. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Place the `<link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />` tag that you have written, in the `head` element since it is a container for metadata about the page -- including links to **stylesheets**, scripts etc.

Placing it in the `<style></style>` tag causes the browser to expect CSS stylesheet language to be found within said tag, of which your `<link>` tag is not. Therefore an attempt will be made to render the content within said tag as CSS in the browser, which will not work.

The selected answer is correct, just wanted to provide some reasoning as to why this does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code:

```
<head>
   <title>Welcome.</title>
   <link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
```

That's it.